# Pillow handles PNG files incorrectly

Tags: python, python-imaging-library

I can successfully convert a rectangular image into a png with transparent rounded corners like this:

[image: .png image with transparent corners]

However, when I take this transparent cornered image and I want to use it in another image generated with Pillow, I end up with this: [image: transparent corners turned black by Pillow]

The transparent corners become black. I've been playing around with this for a while but I can't find any way in which the transparent parts of an image don't turn black once I place them on another image with Pillow.
Here is the code I use:

```
mask = Image.open('Test mask.png').convert('L')
im = Image.open('boat.jpg')
im.resize(mask.size)
output = ImageOps.fit(im, mask.size, centering=(0.5, 0.5))
output.putalpha(mask)
output.save('output.png')

im = Image.open('output.png')

image_bg = Image.new('RGBA', (1292,440), (255,255,255,100))
image_fg = im.resize((710, 400), Image.ANTIALIAS)
image_bg.paste(image_fg, (20, 20))

image_bg.save('output2.jpg')
```

Is there a solution for this? Thanks.

Per some suggestions I exported the 2nd image as a PNG, but then I ended up with an image with holes in it: 
[image]
Obviously I want the second image to have a consistent white background without holes.

Here is what I actually want to end up with. The orange is only placed there to highlight the image itself. It's a rectangular image with white background, with a picture placed into it with rounded corners.
[image]

Comment: can you share your code?

Comment: @Jean-FrançoisFabre added code.

Comment: I believe your 'output.png' has the transparent corners but your final 'output2.jpg' does not. Correct? If so, you cannot have transparent color in JPG. Can you save the final file as PNG and use it?

Comment: @CarlosMermingas Ah, I see what you mean. I can't believe it works this way. I would expect that the corners remain transparent and the background behind it is visible. However, when I export the final image as a PNG, it puts a hole into the corners, meaning that even the background white layer becomes transparent on the corners. That is also not the right solution :(

Comment: It appears that you are creating image_bg with a black background, try changing the values and you'll see that you can get the black to become anything. Furthermore Carlos is correct, your second image is a jpg e.g. ('output2.jpg') and jpeg does not support transparency.

Comment: So you don't want transparent corners but white corners? In this case, you can use JPG. Just do what @jmercouris suggests: Create your final image with a white background to begin with.

Comment: @jmercouris image_bg is created with white background (255,255,255 = white). However, the transparent corners of the imported PNG actually cut out the image_bg as well, creating 4 holes for no reason. If I convert the background color from RGBA to RGB, then the rounded corners turn black again. I don't know how to change this.

Comment: The problem is here I think: If I convert the background color from RGBA to RGB. You literally removed the alpha. Anyways, it's not clear what you're trying to do here. Can you show an example of a correctly finished product?

Comment: @jmercouris Added expected result.

Comment: I think your problem is with `img_bg.paste(img_fg, ...)` The `paste` method directly copies the pixels from the source to the destination, it doesn't do alpha blending.

Comment: @Blckknght What is the alternative in terms of merging images?

Comment: I'm not a PIL expert by any means, but perhaps you could use `alpha_composite` to merge the partly-transparent foreground image with an opaque background image of the same size, then `paste` the composite over a second, larger background image?

Comment: @Blckknght Perfect! That's exactly what I wanted. Thank you.

Answer (score 2):

If you paste an image with transparent pixels onto another image, the transparent pixels are just copied as well. It looks like you only want to paste the non-transparent pixels. In that case, you need a mask for the `paste` function.

```
image_bg.paste(image_fg, (20, 20), mask=image_fg)
```

Note the third argument here. From the documentation:

> If a mask is given, this method updates only the regions indicated by
>   the mask.  You can use either "1", "L" or "RGBA" images (in the latter
>   case, the alpha band is used as mask). Where the mask is 255, the
>   given image is copied as is.  Where the mask is 0, the current value
>   is preserved.  Intermediate values will mix the two images together,
>   including their alpha channels if they have them.

What we did here is provide an RGBA image as mask, and use the alpha channel as mask.